# How to open all files in directory by vim in one file?

Tags: vim, macvim

For example I have directory `VIM` with files `a.sql, b.sql, c.sql, ... x.sql`

How can I open all this files in one big file:
like `all_files.sql` with data of all files in `VIM` directory:

```
  content of file `a.sql`
  content of file `b.sql`
  ...
  content of file `x.sql`
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can:

```
vim all_files.sql
```

then

```
:r!cat /path/*.sql
```

### or

```
cat /path/*.sql| vim -
```

then save as `all_files.sql`

Comment: Thank you mate :) You're are the BEST :)
I'll accept after 5min, cuz the system doesn't allow me to do it right   now :)

Comment: @whitesiroi if you don't want to do any edit, just merge the files, you don't need vim. you just `cat /path/*.sql > all.sql`

Comment: Love you even more :) Thank you mate very much.